# Use lapack's dgemm (linker error)

Tags: fortran, lapack

How can I multiply two matrices by Lapack package for Fortran? I use gfortran compiler in ubuntu.
My code which doesn't work is:

```
program main

integer, parameter :: n = 10
double precision :: alpha = 1.0, beta = 0.0
real, dimension(10,10) :: a

do i1 = 1,n
  do j1 = 1,n
    a(i1,j1) = j1 + (i1-1)*n
   end do
end do

call cpu_time(start)

call DGEMM('N', 'N', n, n, n, alpha, a, n, a, n, beta, a, n)

call cpu_time(end)
print *, end - start

end program main
```

I used:

```
gfortran 0.f90 -llapack
```

It returned:

```
/tmp/ccPy78g5.o: In function `MAIN__':
0.f90:(.text+0x110): undefined reference to `dgemm_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Have you glanced at the manual? What kind of matrices?

Comment: I added the code which I used and doesn't work.

Comment: What is the exact problem? A simple "it does not work" does not help very much in helping you.

Answer (score 3):

The error message means, that your compiler (gfortran) cannot find `lapack` or rather `dgemm`. Please make sure, that lapack is in your path. Alternatively (I assume you are using Ubuntu Linux) you could try `-lblas` instead (after installing it, of course - afaik ubuntu follows a different naming convention):

```
gfortran 0.f90 -lblas -llapack
```

**Edit**

Alternatively, you may pass the path to the library directly as an argument. By default, gfortran will look in `/usr/local/lib/``for the specified libraries. If the library is located somewhere else, you may instead use something like

```
gfortran 0.f90 /path/to/my/library.a
```

Comment: How can I find out that lapack is installed and is in the path?

Comment: On Ubuntu Linux, you libraries are located most likely in /usr/local/lib. You can use synaptics to find out, if lapack/blas (-dev!) is installed or not. I added a paragraph on how to use differently located libaries.

Comment: Or add `-L/usr/local/lib` to add this directory to the linker search path.